# git diff - git difftool - vimdiff - How to compare two files from column 1 to 72 - It's possible config one of this tools

Tags: git, compare, cobol, git-diff, vimdiff

For mainframe modernization I'm using git to modify my Cobol programs.

To compare two programs one in Dev stage and another in Prod stage, I would like to compare them only from column 1 to 72.

I tried using git diff, git difftool and vimdiff but I don't know how to customize or set them and replace the default which is 80 to 72.

I tried to find the .vimrc file on my pc but the result is not a success.

Unsuccessfully, I tried to set the tool via vim but that does not work.

Please, could you help me?
Regards.

I tried to find the .vimrc file on my pc to set the new parameters but I don't find it
I tried to set the tool via vim but that does not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify [text conversions to use when prepping files for diffing,](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffltdrivergttextconv)

```
echo \*.cob diff=strip73on >>.git/info/attributes

git config diff.strip73on.textconv 'cut -c1-72'
```

and from then on anything using git's diff core in that clone will ignore those files' line numbers.

Comment: By the way folks, these commands are for Unix and can be issued in a Git Gui window by selecting "Repository" menu, select 'Git Bash'.  The 'cut' command can easily be modified to strip leading sequence number cols 1-5 from traditional Cobol statements.
@jthill, I looked long and hard for this solution to uncontrolled source sequence field cols 73-80; thank you so much.  This answer deserves to be more widely known among Git users, especially those who may also require '--no-index'.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the first 72 characters of either of the files using `cut` and compare those (replace `file.1` and `file.2` with actual paths to the files you want to compare):

```bash
COL=72
FILE_A=file.1
FILE_B=file.2
diff --unified -- <(cat "$FILE_A" | cut -c 1-$COL) <(cat "$FILE_B" | cut -c 1-$COL)
```

If you want to compare side by side, use `diff --side-by-side`.